# Monotonicity of log determinant of Gaussian kernel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, machine-learning, kernels

Let \begin{equation} k({x},{y}) = \sigma \exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2\theta^2}\right)\end{equation}
be a squared-exponential (Gaussian) kernel, with $\sigma,\vartheta>0$. Consider, for a set of $N$ distinct points $x_1,\ldots, x_N \in \mathbb{R}$, the corresponding kernel matrix $\mathbf{K}$, with entries
\begin{equation}
K_{ij} = k({x}_i,{x}_j).
\end{equation} In Carl Edward Rasmussen's book
(http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf, page 113), it is stated that the complexity (penalty) $\log \vert \mathbf{K}\vert$ of a Gaussian process model with kernel matrix $\mathbf{K}$ decreases with the lengthscale, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\log \vert \mathbf{K} \vert}{d\theta} \leq 0.
\end{equation}
Even though this seems to be common knowledge among people who employ Gaussian processes, I am struggling to prove it, and would like to know how to do so.

**Edit:** I have tried employing the following:

- First, note that $\vert \mathbf{K} \vert = \prod_{n=1}^N \sigma_n(x_n)$, where the elements of $\mathbf{k}_n$ and $\mathbf{K}_n$ are given by $k_{n,i}=k(x_n,x_i)$ and $K_{n,ij}= k({x}_i,{x}_j)$, respectively, i.e., $\sigma_n(x_n)$ denotes the posterior GP variance at $x_n$ with respect to the first $n-1$ data points. This identity follows directly from the Schur determinant formula.

I am able to show that the identity holds if all $\sigma_n(x_n)$ decrease monotonically with the lengthscale, which would imply the desired result. To this end, I am trying to apply the following, which can be found, e.g., in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00445.pdf

- $\sigma_n(x_n) = \sigma \langle k(x,\cdot) (\Phi_n \Phi_n^{\top} + \sigma I)^{-1} k(x,\cdot) \rangle_k$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_k$ denotes the inner product of the reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) with reproducing kernel $k(\cdot,\cdot)$, and $\Phi_n: H_k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear operator, specified as $\Phi_n = (k(x_1,\cdot),\ldots,k(x_n,\cdot))^{\top}$.

Now, it can be easily shown that, for two lengthscales $\theta < \tilde{\theta}$ and corresponding kernels $k_{\theta}(\cdot,\cdot)$, $k_{\tilde\theta}(\cdot,\cdot)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\langle k_{\theta}(x,\cdot) (\Phi_{\theta,n} \Phi_{\theta,n}^{\top} + \sigma I) k_{\theta}(x,\cdot) \rangle_{k_{\theta}} \leq \langle k_{\tilde\theta}(x,\cdot) (\Phi_{\tilde\theta,n} \Phi_{\tilde\theta,n}^{\top} + \sigma I) k_{\tilde\theta}(x,\cdot) \rangle_{k_{\tilde\theta}} .
\end{equation}

What I am now wondering is: does this also imply
\begin{equation}
\langle k_{\theta}(x,\cdot) (\Phi_{\theta,n} \Phi_{\theta,n}^{\top} + \sigma I)^{-1} k_{\theta}(x,\cdot) \rangle_{k_{\theta}} \geq \langle k_{\tilde\theta}(x,\cdot) (\Phi_{\tilde\theta,n} \Phi_{\tilde\theta,n}^{\top} + \sigma I)^{-1} k_{\tilde\theta}(x,\cdot) \rangle_{k_{\tilde\theta}} ?
\end{equation}